# Youtube API Video Stream Broken on Site, Need Some Direction

Tags: youtube-api

Apologies for the vague title of my question. I'm just trying to figure out why a Youtube video stream on a friend's Wordpress site suddenly broke.

I'm trying to decipher it now, but I thought I'd post here to see if anyone could point me in the correct direction while I make heads or tails of this.

Thank you.

Page in question: http://www.advocatedaily.com/advocatetv/
Error on page:

```
Warning: main() [function.main]: Node no longer exists in /home/advocate/public_html/wp-content/themes/process/advocate-tv.php on line 45

Warning: main() [function.main]: Node no longer exists in /home/advocate/public_html/wp-content/themes/process/advocate-tv.php on line 45

Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object in /home/advocate/public_html/wp-content/themes/process/advocate-tv.php on line 48
```

Lines 40 through 55:

```
 // get video player URL
                  $attrs = $media->group->player->attributes();
                  $watch = $attrs['url']; 

                  // get video thumbnail
                  $attrs = $media->group->thumbnail[0]->attributes();
                  $thumbnail = $attrs['url']; 

                  // get <yt:duration> node for video length
                  $yt = $media->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
                  $attrs = $yt->duration->attributes();
                  $length = $attrs['seconds']; 

                  //get <yt:videoId> node for Video ID
                  $yt = $media->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
                  $playlistVideoID = $yt->videoid;
```

Full snippet of problem area:

```
    </div>
    <div id="mainPlaylist" class="grid_6 omega">
        <h3 class="title">Legal Feed with Kate Wheeler</h3>
        <ul id="playlists">
            <?php
                // Loop through each video in each playlist

                // read feed into SimpleXML object
                // *Moved into header to load main Video as well
                $playlistFeedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/6549D4CA7BB99B16?v=2';
                $sxml = simplexml_load_file($playlistFeedURL);

                // iterate over entries in feed
                foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {
                  // get nodes in media: namespace for media information
                  $media = $entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');

                  // get video player URL
                  $attrs = $media->group->player->attributes();
                  $watch = $attrs['url']; 

                  // get video thumbnail
                  $attrs = $media->group->thumbnail[0]->attributes();
                  $thumbnail = $attrs['url']; 

                  // get <yt:duration> node for video length
                  $yt = $media->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
                  $attrs = $yt->duration->attributes();
                  $length = $attrs['seconds']; 

                  //get <yt:videoId> node for Video ID
                  $yt = $media->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
                  $playlistVideoID = $yt->videoid;


                  // get <yt:stats> node for viewer statistics
                  $yt = $entry->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
                  $attrs = $yt->statistics->attributes();
                  $viewCount = $attrs['viewCount']; 

                  // get <gd:rating> node for video ratings
                  $gd = $entry->children('http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'); 
                  if ($gd->rating) {
                    $attrs = $gd->rating->attributes();
                    $rating = $attrs['average'];  
                  } else {
                    $rating = 0; 
                  }

                  ?>
                  <div class="item">
                      <span class="thumbnail left" rel="<?php echo $entry->id; ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo $watch; ?>" rel="<?php echo $playlistVideoID; ?>" onclick="_run();"><img src="<?php echo $thumbnail;?>" /></a>
                      </span>
                      <a href="<?php echo $watch; ?>" rel="<?php echo $playlistVideoID; ?>" onclick="_run();"><?php echo $media->group->title; ?></a>
                      <span class="attr">Duration:</span> <?php printf('%0.2f', $length/60); ?> min.
                      <div class="clear"></div>
                  </div>      
                <?php
                }           
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="hr-single grid_16"></div>
</div>
<div class="article grid_10">
    <div id="recentUploads">
        <h3 class="grid_8">Recent Uploads</h3>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <ul>
            <?php
            // Loop through each video in each playlist

            // read feed into SimpleXML object
            // *Moved into header to load main Video as well
            $playlistFeedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/755260781A134FFF?v=2';
            $sxml = simplexml_load_file($playlistFeedURL);

            // iterate over entries in feed
            foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {
              // get nodes in media: namespace for media information
              $media = $entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');

              // get video player URL
              $attrs = $media->group->player->attributes();
              $watch = $attrs['url']; 

              // get video thumbnail
              $attrs = $media->group->thumbnail[0]->attributes();
              $thumbnail = $attrs['url']; 

              // get <yt:duration> node for video length
              $yt = $media->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
              $attrs = $yt->duration->attributes();
              $length = $attrs['seconds']; 

              //get <yt:videoId> node for Video ID
              $yt = $media->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
              $playlistVideoID = $yt->videoid;


              // get <yt:stats> node for viewer statistics
              $yt = $entry->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
              $attrs = $yt->statistics->attributes();
              $viewCount = $attrs['viewCount']; 

              // get <gd:rating> node for video ratings
              $gd = $entry->children('http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'); 
              if ($gd->rating) {
                $attrs = $gd->rating->attributes();
                $rating = $attrs['average'];  
              } else {
                $rating = 0; 
              }

              ?>
              <div class="item">
                  <div class="thumbnail left" rel="<?php echo $entry->id; ?>">
                    <a href="<?php echo $watch; ?>" rel="<?php echo $playlistVideoID; ?>" onclick="_run();"><img src="<?php echo $thumbnail;?>" /></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="">
                      <a href="<?php echo $watch; ?>" rel="<?php echo $playlistVideoID; ?>" onclick="_run();"><?php echo $media->group->title; ?></a>
                      <span class="attr">Duration:</span> <?php printf('%0.2f', $length/60); ?> min.
                      <p><?php echo $media->group->description; ?></p>  
                  </div>
                  <div class="clear"></div>
              </div>      
            <?php
            }           
        ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the same thing that happened to me may have happened to you.

As per your code it seems the API isn't correctly finding the playlist
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/6549D4CA7BB99B16?v=2

In an attempt to fix my own troubled calls I added the PL to the Playlist ID : **PL**6549D4CA7BB99B16
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL6549D4CA7BB99B16?v=2

While googling this, I found a blog post referencing something about adding the ability to include the PL to the calls. 
apiblog.youtube.com/2012/08/playlists-now-with-more-pl.html

In my quick searches I didn't notice anything about them removing the old way of it sending the playlist ID.